# Highlight only one element from set during animation

Tags: jquery

I wrote myself a jquery plugin called marquee (I think there is no need for explanation what it does)

This plugin has to do one more thing I am partly able to achieve. Highlight one word during animation when it's in the middle third of the container.

My animation is done like this

```
var reset = function() {
    $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
    $(this).animate({ "margin-left": (-w-30)+"px" },{
        duration:s.interval,
        easing:'linear',
        done:reset, // don't forget to uncomment
        step:_highlight
    });
};
reset.call(e.find(".text-banner-wrapper"));
```

And the _highlight function is written as follows

```
_highlight = function(e,f){
    var f = $(f.elem).closest('.text-carousel');
    var w = f.width();
    f.find('.item').each(function(){
        var o = $(this).offset().left-f.offset().left;
        if(o<((2*w)/3) && o>w/3){
            if(!$(this).prev().is(".active")){
                $(this)
                       .css('color',f.data("highlightcolor"))
                       .addClass("active");
            }           
        }
        else
            $(this).removeClass("active").removeAttr("style");
    });
}
```

You can see my approach, but it doesn't work as expected. I am able to add and remove the style and class, but if the words are short it highlights more of them. Can anybody help me with that?

Thank you!

**EDIT**
Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xprdmyw5/) which output window has to be resized very much so that it works properly from the start.

Comment: Be great if you could throw a jsfiddle together.

Comment: gimme a sec, I'll update the question

Comment: updated, please keep in mind, that it has it's buggy behavior is visible only when the window is really wide

Comment: Come on guys, I'm sure you don't have to be ashamed for your genius ideas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to check if there is already an active item and don't highlight the new one if so.

```
if(!$('.item.active').length) {
    $(this).css('color',f.data("highlightcolor")).addClass("active");   
}
```

So your highlight function would look like this:

```
_highlight = function(e,f){
    var f = $(f.elem).closest('.text-carousel');
    var w = f.width();
    f.find('.item').each(function(){
        var o = $(this).offset().left-f.offset().left;
        if(o<((2*w)/3) && o>w/3){
            if(!$('.item.active').length) {
                $(this).css('color',f.data("highlightcolor")).addClass("active");   
            }
        }
        else
            $(this).removeClass("active").removeAttr("style");
    });
}
```

Comment: haha yeah, often thinking simle is the most complicated thing to do

Comment: Exactly, often after writing 1000 lines of code and then finding out there is that one case where it doesn't work as you wish it to and can't think simple anymore. Thanks again. Have a nice day.